# Play Games Achievements disappear sometimes - Android

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-games, leaderboard, achievements

I just implemented Play Games in my Android game (Achievements, Leaderboards and Save Game)
The game has 20 achievements.

I signed the APK and I uploaded the game to Internal Test. I successfully login with Play Games, I successfully unlock achievements, but sometimes the unlocked achievements become locked and sometimes when I start the Intent to show all the achievements, the achievements disappear and the message "No achievements for this game" is shown.

Before I publish the game to Production, I want to make sure that the problem is not in my implementation.

Is it a Play Games bug, or I make something wrong?

Maybe I made something wrong with the credential process? These are the steps I made:

1. I created the Android OAuth 2.0 Client ID credential in Cloud Console and I completed the SHA-1 with the one I found in Google Play Console -> Setup -> App Integrity -> App signing key certificate (not the "Upload key certificate" SHA-1)
2. I also added the same SHA-1 in Firebase Console -> Project Settings
3. I enabled in Firebase Console the Play Games Sign-in. To enable Play Games Sign-in in Firebase, I should complete the Client ID and Client Secret ID. I copied the Client Id and Client Secret Id from the Cloud Project, from Web Application credential.
4. I enabled in Google Play Console the Play Games Services, and I selected the Android Client ID created at #1
5. I added in Manifest the AppId copied from Google Play Console -> Play Games Services -> Configuration -> Authorization -> Application Id

There is also a problem with SavedGames. Sometimes the bytes are empty and I cannot restore the player's progress.

Is there something wrong with the my SHA-1? Or am I missing something?